# Doubt in Murray-von Neumann equivalence

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras, projection, von-neumann-algebras

> I'm trying to understand the following proof:

[image]

> I understand the proof entirely except the displayed formula after "Hence we have". Basically I don't see why $$e_{2n}-e_{2n+1} \sim f_{2n+1}-f_{2n+1}.$$ Can someone explain why this must be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number 2 is from replacing $n$ with $2n$.

If you put $w=u(e_n-e_{n+1})$, then
$$
w^*w=(e_n-e_{n+1})u^*u(e_n-e_{n+1})=e_n-e_{n+1},
$$
$$
ww^*=u(e_n-e_{n+1})u^*=f_{n+1}-f_{n+2}.
$$

Comment: How do you get $(e_n-e_{n+1})u^*u(e_n-e_{n+1})=e_n-e_{n+1}$?

Comment: $u^*ue_n=e\,e_n=e_n$.